# Rspec error 'field' cant be blank, when given a not blank field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have one very anoing error while testing my simple app's photo model.

my spec for photos

```
describe Photo do
  before { @photo = Photo.create!(image: "5513770961_a73024a244_z.jpg", wraper: true, to_slider: true) }
  subject { @photo }

  it {should respond_to(:image)}
  it {should respond_to(:wraper)}
  it {should respond_to(:to_slider)}
  it {should be_valid}
end
```

when this spec executes, it returns a strange error

```
Failure/Error: before { @photo = Photo.create!(image: "5513770961_a73024a244_z.jpg", wraper: true, to_slider: true) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Image can't be blank
```

My test db is prepared and loaded, don't simply can figure out this...
Thanks for help..)

Photo model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image,  :gallery_id, :wraper, :to_slider

  belongs_to :gallery

  validates :image, presence: true

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Answer (score 0):

please just don't give the image name give the the full path like

make image attribute accessible

by adding this line to the model

attr_accessible :image

example: ---

```
before { @photo = Photo.create!(image: "#{Rails.root}/spec/images/5513770961_a73024a244_z.jpg", wraper: true, to_slider: true) }
```

Comment: @AndreyYasinishyn make image as accessible attribute.

Comment: I added my model to this issue